# Рекурсия на pascal

Tags: pascal, рекурсия

Помогите рекурсивно описать функцию `cos(x,k)` на `pascal`, где

```
cos(x,k)=cos(cos(..cos(x)..))(k косинусов)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function cosk(x: Real; k: LongInt): Real;
begin
  if k <= 0 then begin
    cosk := cos(x);
  end else
    cosk := cosk(x, k - 1);
end;
```

Comment: Т.е. функция cos применяется только один раз, а рекурсия сильно озабочена уменьшением k...